# Store Facebook data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a front end page created and want to give a signup option to the user using Facebook. For that I've gone through the registration plugin of Facebook. I know the basics of SQL but don't know how to proceed so as to store the data of the user who sign up using Facebook.

How should I proceed about learning it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create database and table in server and  connect to database and store the value in table using php

Comment: can u give an example using a demo app

Answer (score 0):

[Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/MySQL-tutorials/PHP-MySQL-Essential-Training/119003-2.html?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3aphp%2bmysql%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2): (or similar) might fill in some of the web programming basics for you.